# Recover unsaved .csv file changes

Tags: excel, csv

Does anyone know a way to recover changes made in a .csv that were not saved when excel 2007 was closed.
At the moment, I don't see any way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Check all the temporary files created recently.  Especially alongside the file you opened.  There are a few temp folders in the system that Excel may use.  `C:\Windows\temp` is the main one, but it is usually under the Users folder in later versions of windows.  Eg: `C:\Users\YourUserName\Local Settings\Temp`

If you find any files that look like Excel temps, take a copy and rename the extension and then try to open it.

(Your only real chance is if auto-save kicked in and saved a copy - to a temp file - when you still had your new changes in the document.  Otherwise the changes are lost I'm afraid)

Answer (score 0):

If option #1 doesn't resolve your problem in Excel, go to File->Options->Save.  Hopefully your AutoRecover file location, under the third box, will be populated with an address.